# The opposite thing to the ringed space

Tags: ring-theory, sheaf-theory

It is common that
a sheaf of rings is a sheaf (of sets) $\cal F$ on a space $X$ such that for each open $U\subseteq X$, ${\cal F}(U)$ has
the structure of a ring and for each open $V \subseteq U$ , the restriction map ${\cal F}(U) \to {\cal F} (V)$ is a ring homomorphism. My question is this: Can we naturally obtain the **opposite thing**: for each open $V \subseteq U$  (a/the?) map ${\cal F}(V) \to {\cal F} (U)$ is a ring homomorphism. I think that there is some obstacle in general, but I'm not sure about its nature.

Comment: Sometimes $U\mapsto \mathcal{F}(X-U)$ will be a sheaf of rings

Comment: You defined a presheaf of rings, not a sheaf of rings. And we can easily have presheafs going “the other way” - this is a presheaf for $Ring^{op}$. We could even extend this to a sheaf for $Ring^{op}$, since $Ring$ has all colimits.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking here. Are you asking if for every presheaf $F$ we also get natural maps $F(V) \to F(U)$ for all opens $V \subseteq U$? If so, the question is no. Consider the basic example: continuous functions on a space. Or do you really just ask if we can write down the definition of a copresheaf? Sure. But then, what do you want to know about them?

Comment: Right. One comment says "yes":  "opposite presheaves of rings", nothing will stop you while the other says "no": If so, the question is no.  So where is the truth ?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg What can be an argument for this: we cannot obtain $C(V)\to C(U)$ for $V\subseteq U$ in general ? I have some intuition but not a proof of this claim.